# MapIndexed and Compile

Tags: bugs, compile

I am having trouble compiling a function that uses the `MapIndexed` function on the second level. The compilation runs fine, but at evaluation time I get an error that I cannot explain right now.

The following scenario shows the problem:

First I define a compiled version and a noncompiled version of a simple funciton using `MapIndexed`:

```
MapIndexedCompileTest = Compile[{{list1, _Real, 2}, {list2, _Real, 2}}, 
                          MapIndexed[list1[[#2[[1]], #2[[2]]]] + #1 &, list2, {2}]]

MapIndexedTest[list1_, list2_] := MapIndexed[list1[[#2[[1]], #2[[2]]]] + #1 &, list2, {2}]
```

`MapIndexedTest` shows that the function works just fine:

```
MapIndexedTest[{{1, 2}, {1, 2}}, {{1, 2}, {1, 2}}]
```

But `MapIndexedCompiledTest` yields the error:

> ```
> "CompiledFunction::cflist: Nontensor object generated; proceeding with 
>  uncompiled evaluation"
> ```

when evaluated the same way:

```
MapIndexedCompileTest[{{1, 2}, {1, 2}}, {{1, 2}, {1, 2}}]
```

Does anybody know what goes wrong?

**New intel I just got when reading answers:**

The problem seems to be that the index represented by the second argument is not correct when using compiled. To see that I defined the following functions, which should just return the current index inside the Mapping function:

```
MapIndexedGiveIndexCompiled = Compile[{{p, _Real, 2}}, MapIndexed[#2 & , p, {2}]];
MapIndexedGiveIndex[p_] := MapIndexed[#2 & , p, {2}];
```

The above functions should obviously return the same results when used on a 2 rank tensor, but they do not, `MapIndexedGiveIndexCompiled` delivers the wrong result:

```
MapIndexedGiveIndexCompiled[{{1, 2}, {3, 4}}]
```

delivers:

> {{{1}, {2}}, {{1}, {2}}}

while `MapIndexedGiveIndex` returns the expected result:

> {{{1, 1}, {1, 2}}, {{2, 1}, {2, 2}}}

This should explain why `[[2]]` is not working, but overall it looks like a bug to me.

Comment: Use `#2[[-1]]` or `Last@#2` instead of #2[[2]] is OK.

Comment: Although it's possible this is a bug I think it is more likely that it isn't fully supported.  There are other functions that only work properly in Compile in a limited fashion.  Thanks for bringing this to my attention.

Comment: Suspect it is a bug in the sense that it didn't compile into something equivalent. Ordinarily, non-compileable code should produce a message to that effect and be handled using a callback to the main evaluator. In this case it seems that `Compile` thought it could compile your code, but actually it can't. halirutan's answer suggests that this is a problem with the type inference mechanism. @Mr.Wizard

Comment: @Oleksandr On your expertise with Compile I am going to tag this as a bug.

Answer (score 9):

It seems this has something to do with the element access of the anonymous function argument `#2`. One possible solution which additionally makes it easier to read is

```
f = Compile[{{list1, _Real, 2}, {list2, _Real, 2}},
  MapIndexed[
   With[{x = First[#2], y = Last[#2]},
     list1[[x, y]] + #1] &, list2, {2}]]
```

What I don't understand is, that you could do something even more verbose by defining two functions. The first one does exactly what you do inside the `MapIndexed`

```
f1 = Compile[{{v1, _Real, 2}, {v, _Real, 0}, {p, _Integer, 1}},
  Module[{x = p[[1]], y = p[[2]]},
   v1[[x, y]] + v
   ]
  ]
```

And you will see that e.g.

```
ff[{{1, 2}, {3, 4}}, 3, {1, 2}]
```

runs without complains. But if you incorporate it into the other function

```
f = With[{f1 = f1},
  Compile[{{list1, _Real, 2}, {list2, _Real, 2}}, MapIndexed[
    f1[list1, #1, #2] &, list2, {2}],
   CompilationOptions -> {"InlineCompiledFunctions" -> True}
   ]
  ]
```

you get the error message again. When you change the element access in `f1` to `First` and `Last`, then it works again. This suggests, that compile cannot properly determine that `#2` is indeed a tensor where `#2[[2]]` is valid but the situation remains weird.

Comment: Thanks for your hints. Further investigations brought me to the additional information I now included in the question above. The compiled version seems to give the wrong index. Any idea how to fix it, or is it actually a bug?