# MapThread and Compile

Tags: performance-tuning, compile, map

After discovering that MapIndexed cannot be used with `compile` (see [MapIndexed and Compile](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/31588/mapindexed-and-compile)) I am now trying do implement similar functionality using a combination of `MapThread` and `Map`. Unfortunately I am running into problems even when only using `MapThread`.

Here is a test-scenario:

Create Lists first:

```
A = {{1, 2}, {2, 3}};
B = {{{1, 2, 3}, {2, 3, 4}}, {{2, 3, 4}, {3, 4, 5}}};
```

The I simply run `MapThread` with function `List[]` to obtain a suitable combination of those lists and put the whole thing inside a `Compile`-statement:

```
test = Compile[{{B, _Real, 3}, {A, _Real, 2}}, MapThread[List[#1, #2, #3] &, {B, A, A}, 2]];
```

But when running `test[B,A]` I get the following compile error:

> CompiledFunction::cfex: Could not complete external evaluation at instruction 15; proceeding with uncompiled evaluation.

When using `CompilePrint[test]` instruction 15 shows a call to `MainEvaluate`.

Unfortunately I currently have no clue how to fix that problem. Any hint is appreciated.

Comment: I don't think you are allowed to have lists of that irregular shape, i.e. `{{1, 2, 3}, 1, 1}`. Note that it works as expected with `Plus[#1,#2,#3]&`. See for instance `Compile[{}, Block[{a = {1, 2}, b = 3}, {a, b}]][]`

Comment: indeed, Compile only works with rectangular arrays of consistent type -- because otherwise they cannot be packed. Arrays in Compile are packed arrays, and ragged arrays destroy packing, and hence, compilation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Incorporating the comments into an answer:

> I don't think you are allowed to have lists of that irregular shape,
>   i.e. `{{1, 2, 3}, 1, 1}`. Note that it works as expected with
>   `Plus[#1,#2,#3]&`. See for instance `Compile[{}, Block[{a = {1, 2}, b
>   = 3}, {a, b}]][]` –  [ssch](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/1517/ssch) Oct 15 '13 at 14:20
>
> indeed, Compile only works with rectangular arrays of consistent type -- because otherwise they cannot be packed. Arrays in Compile are
>   packed arrays, and ragged arrays destroy packing, and hence,
>   compilation. –  [Andreas Lauschke](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/1598/andreas-lauschke) Oct 15 '13 at 14:39