# Compile a precomputed list-type expression

Tags: performance-tuning, compile

I precompute an expression which takes pretty long to evaluate (i.e. for my real problem `tmp[2]` takes quite long) and I want to see if runtime can be improved using `Compile`. Consider `expr` below which can in my case either be a vector or a matrix. It is then "transformed" into a function like `tmp[t]`. Using `Compile` I ran into the following issue:

```
ClearAll[tmp, fun, fun2, fun3, expr];
expr = {Sin[t], Cos[t]};
tmp[t_] = expr;
fun = Compile[{{t, _Real}}, tmp[t]];
fun2 = Compile[{{t, _Real}}, expr];
fun3 = Compile[{{t, _Real}}, {Sin[t], Cos[t]}];
```

Now evaluating the three variants yields

***Option 1:***

```
fun[2.]
```

> CompiledFunction::cfex: Could not complete external evaluation at instruction 1; proceeding with uncompiled evaluation.

```
(* {0.909297, -0.416147} *)
```

***Option 2:***

```
fun2[2.]
```

> CompiledFunction::cfte: Compiled expression {Sin[t],Cos[t]} should be a rank 1 tensor of machine-size real numbers.
>   CompiledFunction::cfex: Could not complete external evaluation at instruction 1; proceeding with uncompiled evaluation.

```
(* {Sin[t], Cos[t]} *)
```

***Option 3:***

```
fun3[2.]
(* {0.909297, -0.416147} *)
```

Considering that

```
ClearAll[fun4,tmp2];
tmp2[t_] = expr[[1]];
fun4 = Compile[{{t, _Real}}, tmp2[t]];
fun4[2.]
(* 0.909297 *)
```

Concluding, I could apply `Compile` to all elements of my list and then merge the compiled functions into a single function, but that seems rather complicated and possibly what I need, i.e. something along the lines of `fun`, is easily realized if one knows how.

**So the question is**: Can anyone please let me know how to run `Compile` on a list that is stored in some precomputed expression?

### Edit & Update

I have just found something [related](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/34063/21606) but I cannot get a solution out of it. The issue might be related to packed vs unpacked arrays, at least this is what I guess from the linked question.

```
Needs["CompiledFunctionTools`"];
CompilePrint[fun]
CompilePrint[fun3]
```

shows that `fun` has a call to `MainEvaluate` whilst `fun3` does not:

```
(* output for fun *)
1 argument
        2 Real registers
        Underflow checking off
        Overflow checking off
        Integer overflow checking on
        RuntimeAttributes -> {}

        R0 = A1
        Result = R1

1   R1 = MainEvaluate[ Hold[tmp][ R0]]
2   Return


(* output for fun3 *)
1 argument
        3 Real registers
        1 Tensor register
        Underflow checking off
        Overflow checking off
        Integer overflow checking on
        RuntimeAttributes -> {}

        R0 = A1
        Result = T(R1)0

1   R1 = Sin[ R0]
2   R2 = Cos[ R0]
3   T(R1)0 = {R1, R2}
4   Return
```

Comment: You need `With[]` for injecting code: `fun4 = With[{e = expr}, Compile[{{t, _Real}}, e]]`. Or, some trickery with `Hold[]`/`ReleaseHold[]`: `fun5 = ReleaseHold[Hold[Compile][{{t, _Real}}, expr]]`.

Comment: @J.M. Thank you very much for this suggestion! If you wish you can turn it into an answer and I will accept. Unfortunately I now run into another error related to a numerical error when evaluating the `CompiledFunction` of my actual problem. Is it better to rewrite the question (shorten its current content) and extend it by the real expression I am working with, or should I rather open a second question purely focussing on that specific issue?

Comment: I am pretty sure this is a dupe, but I am unable to recall where the original is. Your new error ought to be a separate question, I think.